# How to put if in an variable in HTML/PHP

Tags: php, html, email, mailto

I just starded with PHP and dont have a lot of knowledge. But i want to generate a Mail by pressing ona button. That works so far. But now i have for example the Row `Anrede: ".$row["anrede"]."%0D%0A`. This is a ENUM with Herr, Frau and Other. But i also got that in other languages (FR, IT) and i want to output Monsineur for Herr, Madamme for Frau and autres for Other.

I tried it with

```
 "if ($row['anrede'] == 'Herr' ){
              echo "Monsieur";
          }
          if ($row['anrede'] == 'Frau') {
              echo "Madame"; 
          }       
          if ($row['anrede'] == 'other') {
              echo "autres"; 
          }"
```

Here the full code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    </head>
    <body>


    <?php
    $host = "";
    $username = "";
    $password = "";
    $dbname = "";
    $port = "";
    $socket = "";

    // initiate new mysqli object
    $mysqli = new mysqli($host, $username, $password, $dbname, $port, $socket);

    if(mysqli_connect_errno())
    {
      printf("Verbindungsfehler:  %s\n". mysqli_connect_error());
      exit();
    }

    $queryString = "SELECT anrede, vorname, nachname, strasse , plz, ort , strasser, plzr, ortr, firma, funktion, email, sektion, anfahrt, uebernachtung, status, ksprache, usprache, aktiv FROM tab_teilnehmer WHERE aktiv = 1";
    $queryResult = $mysqli->query($queryString);



    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($queryResult)) {

      echo "<tr>";
      echo "<td><a href='mailto:" . $row["email"] . "?subject=Test&amp;body=      
------------------DE------------------    
%0D%0AVielen Dank für Ihre Anmeldung Frau/Herr " . $row["nachname"] ."
%0D%0AHier Ihre Anmeldedaten:%0D%0A%0D%0A
Anrede:: ".$row["anrede"]."%0D%0A
Vorname: ".$row["vorname"]."%0D%0A
Nachname: ".$row["nachname"]."%0D%0A
Strasse: ".$row["strasse"]."%0D%0A
PLZ/Ort: ".$row["plz"].", ".$row["ort"]."%0D%0A
Strasse(Rechn.): ".$row["strasser"]."%0D%0A
PLZ/Ort(Rechn.): ".$row["plzr"].", ".$row["ortr"]."%0D%0A
Firma: ".$row["firma"]."%0D%0A
Funktion: ".$row["funktion"]."%0D%0A
E-Mail: ".$row["email"]."%0D%0A
Anfahrt: ".$row["anfahrt"]."%0D%0A
Übernachtungsart: ".$row["uebernachtung"]."%0D%0A
Sektion: ".$row["sektion"]."%0D%0A
Status: ".$row["status"]."%0D%0A
Korrespondenz-/Übersetzungssprache: ".$row["ksprache"].", ".$row["usprache"]."%0D%0A%0D%0A
------------------FR------------------
%0D%0AMerci beaucoup pour votre inscription madame/monsineur " . $row["nachname"] ."
%0D%0AVoici vos identifiants de connexion:%0D%0A%0D%0A
Anrede: ".$row["anrede"]."%0D%0A
Vorname: ".$row["vorname"]."%0D%0A
Nachname: ".$row["nachname"]."%0D%0A
Strasse: ".$row["strasse"]."%0D%0A
PLZ/Ort: ".$row["plz"].", ".$row["ort"]."%0D%0A
Strasse(Rechn.): ".$row["strasser"]."%0D%0A
PLZ/Ort(Rechn.): ".$row["plzr"].", ".$row["ortr"]."%0D%0A
Firma: ".$row["firma"]."%0D%0A
Funktion: ".$row["funktion"]."%0D%0A
E-Mail: ".$row["email"]."%0D%0A
Anfahrt: ".$row["anfahrt"]."%0D%0A
Übernachtungsart: ".$row["uebernachtung"]."%0D%0A
Sektion: ".$row["sektion"]."%0D%0A
Status: ".$row["status"]."%0D%0A
Korrespondenz-/Übersetzungssprache: ".$row["ksprache"].", ".$row["usprache"]."%0D%0A%0D%0A
------------------IT------------------
%0D%0AGrazie mille per la vostra registrazione signora/signore " . $row["nachname"] ."
%0D%0AEcco i tuoi dati di accesso:%0D%0A%0D%0A
Anrede: ".$row["anrede"]."%0D%0A
Vorname: ".$row["vorname"]."%0D%0A
Nachname: ".$row["nachname"]."%0D%0A
Strasse: ".$row["strasse"]."%0D%0A
PLZ/Ort: ".$row["plz"].", ".$row["ort"]."%0D%0A
Strasse(Rechn.): ".$row["strasser"]."%0D%0A
PLZ/Ort(Rechn.): ".$row["plzr"].", ".$row["ortr"]."%0D%0A
Firma: ".$row["firma"]."%0D%0A
Funktion: ".$row["funktion"]."%0D%0A
E-Mail: ".$row["email"]."%0D%0A
Anfahrt: ".$row["anfahrt"]."%0D%0A
Übernachtungsart: ".$row["uebernachtung"]."%0D%0A
Sektion: ".$row["sektion"]."%0D%0A
Status: ".$row["status"]."%0D%0A
Korrespondenz-/Übersetzungssprache: ".$row["ksprache"].", ".$row["usprache"]."
      '>Mail</a></td>"; 
        echo "</tr>";
    } 

    ?>  

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm not very sure why there is so much duplication in the above but I can say that the generated HTML will not be valid as you have no `table` tags but simply start using `tr` etc

Comment: Can you reduce the code to the minimal parts you're stuggling with, and provide your attempts of solving the problem?

Comment: Generating all of that text, complete with line breaks as inline code for the email body is probably not the best way to proceed - this I feel is likely to break quite easily

Comment: "But i also got that in other languages (FR, IT)" how do you determine which language to use?

Comment: First of all `'Herr''` needs to be `'Herr'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to stop the printing, then add the if condition, then continue printing. Or you could consider a ternary, but I would stick with the way your thinking for better readability.

Like so:

```
echo "<td><a href='mailto:" . $row["email"] . "?subject=Test&amp;body=      
------------------DE------------------    
%0D%0AVielen Dank für Ihre Anmeldung Frau/Herr " . $row["nachname"] ."
%0D%0AHier Ihre Anmeldedaten:%0D%0A%0D%0A
Anrede:: ";

if ($row['anrede'] == 'Herr' ){
    echo "Monsieur";
} else if ($row['anrede'] == 'Frau') {
    echo "Madame"; 
} else if ($row['anrede'] == 'other') {
    echo "autres"; 
}

echo "%0D%0A
Vorname: ".$row["vorname"]."%0D%0A
......";
// continue echo
```

Comment: What is the error? Edited my answer, replacing `'Herr''` with `'Herr'`

Comment: Thank u very much!

Answer (score 2):

Maybe something like this

Add this inside looping (your while)

```
if ($row['anrede'] == 'Herr' ){
    $temp = "Monsieur";
}
if ($row['anrede'] == 'Frau') {
    $temp = "Madame";
}
if ($row['anrede'] == 'other') {
    $temp = "autres";
}
```

You need set the value into the variables, based on `anrede` value.
if `anrede` value is `Frau`, set `$temp` value with `Madame`. And call `$temp` where you want.

Answer (score 0):

I would propose this `switch` snippet, it protects against notice, when `$row['anrede']` would not be set and also with `echo`-ing instead of using `$temp` variable.

```php
$anrede = isset($row['anrede']) ? $row['anrede'] : null;

switch($anrede) {
 case 'Herr':
   echo 'Monsieur';
 break;
 case 'Frau':
   echo 'Madame';
 break;
 default:
   echo 'autres';
}
```